# npm error while using npx create-react-app and other npm commands

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have reinstalled Node.

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:35
    throw err
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'semver')
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\config\definition.js:33:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\config\definitions.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
```

Node.js v18.16.0

I expected reinstalling Node to fix the error, but it didn't.

Comment: Have you completely removed and then reinstalled the node from all your files?

Comment: yes i followed this guide https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows/

Comment: Didn't it work for you?

Comment: I'm getting a different error than before. I could try again. Maybe I missed a file.

Comment: Yes, try it out if it solved to you.